# Is there a shorter way to write an equation with a clear pattern?

Tags: arithmetic, pattern-recognition

I have this simple expression:

$$\left(\begin{array}{l}
1\\
+(A)\\
+(A+B)\\
+(A+B+C)\\
+(A+B+C+D)\\
+(A+B+C+D+E)\\
+(A+B+C+D+E+F)\\
+(A+B+C+D+E+F+G)\\
+(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H)\\
+(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H)
\end{array}\right) \cdot 2^{16}$$

Is there a shorter way to write expressions which have clear patterns?

Comment: Are the last two terms supposed to be the same? Why are there parentheses all over the place?

Comment: Would $(1+9A+8B+7C+6D+5E+4F+3G+2H)\times 2^{16}$ do?

Comment: By the way, this is **not** an equation; it is an expression (note the lack of an equals sign...)

Comment: Thank you both, I'm far from a mathematician so forgive my ineptitude in explaining myself. We were reverse engineering a key-gen in class and this was it's progress. The parentheses represent each step in the key-gen algorithm. @Maazul The question I'm seeking is to show in shorthand the progression of this expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if we let $a_0=A, a_1=B,...,$ then we can express the $n$th term, which we'll call $x_n$, of the sequence $A,A+(A+B),A+(A+B)+(A+B+C),...,$ as $$x_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)a_i$$
so *if* you want the $n$th term, which we'll call $S_n$, of the sequence $1\times 2^{16},(1+A)2^{16},(1+A+(A+B))2^{16},...,$ then set $x_0=0$, and then we can write
$$S_n=(1+x_{n-1})2^{16}$$